# Can't get my PowerShell Function to export to a CSV with value in the file

Tags: powershell, function, csv, scripting, scriptblock

I'm a noob at Powershell, and I'm working on an assignment I already tried to do as much research on my own, but I'm stomped and not getting anywhere.

So, what I'm trying to do is Create a function with a required filename parameter.

This Function will need to do the following: Import the provided CSV file, Filter only to show UT state results, Show only the following properties: state, zip, utility_name, commercial_rate, industrial_rate, residential_rate, Sort the result by Zip code and finally Export the result into a new CSV file

Any help will be appreciated. If there is anything I said that's not clear. Let me know so I can clarify it.

Here's my current function:

```
function Get-SortCity {
>>     param (
>>         #This Parameter is mandatory
>>     [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
>>     [string]$Filename
>>
>>     )#below is my script to import the CSV file, select properties, and then export it to a CSV.
>>     Import-Csv $Filename | Where-Object state -Match utah | Select-Object state, zip, utility_name, commercial_rate, industrial_rate, residential_rate| Sort-Object zip | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\kyros\Downloads\Documents\utahrates.csv
>> }
```

When I run sections of my script manually, I get an error around "Import-Csv $Filename" It tells me Import-Csv: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path' The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again

What am I doing wrong that variable would be empty until I call the function and input a path.

Comment: Function looks fine, are you getting any error? are you ever executing the function?

Comment: I'm not getting any error when I execute the function. It just creates a new file like I want it to but the new csv file that is created is blank.

Comment: run it manually to see where the hangup is

Comment: Ok i ran my script manual and when i run "Import-Csv $Filename" section. I get Import-Csv: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: well you need to provide an actual path to the Csv with your function, like: `Get-SortCity 'the\path\to\theCsv.csv'`

Comment: Ok, I got the issue with the Path taken care of. But when the file is exported to a new CSV file. Why is the new file blank? that is my biggest problem

Comment: @JeremyFrank is it actually matching to anything in your data? Is `utah` in the data or are the states listed as abbreviations so you would need to match `ut` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the

```
Where-Object state -match utah
```

What is utah? Powershell has no idea what you are talking about. It doesn't know that utah is a state.  It tries to resolve utah in the same way it resolved state.  It looks for a property named utah in the input object.  There is no such property.  So the comparison is with $null, and this always fails.

Try this instead

```
Where-Object state -match 'UT'
```

Here 'UT' is a literal string, because of the quotes.  'UT' is a two character abbreviation for the state,  and this may be what's in your input CSV file.  Two letter state abbreviations are upper case,  and so is 'UT'.  If I remember right,  -match is not case sensitive,  but what the heck.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing feedback and being helpful. I tried exactly what you showed, and it worked. Again thank you